# Laying Hardwood in an Octagonal Pattern

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, carpentry, hardwood

Edit: I do not understand how the below is 'opinion-based' more than any other construction question. I am literally asking if carpenters here have advice on how to do a complex flooring pattern. I don't see how answers to that do not add to the wonderful base of knowledge on stack exchange. If you can explain that to me, I'd love to edit and continue the conversation.

I’m going to install a ¾” x 5” solid oak floor (Select quality) in an octagonal room, with concentric octagon “rings” of flooring. Every board will end with a 22.5º miter cut, in which I’ll route a groove and install a spline.

There are 2 options:

1. Rings meet at miters, like this: https://www.svbwoodfloors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/SVB-Foyer-Octagonal-300x300.jpg
2. Rings terminate at “spokes”, which come from a “hub,” like this: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPibuZRZlnDPWTnkXFXrxyndQ_xijo6Hx2kQ&usqp=CAU

Either takes a ton of precision. I’m a solid carpenter – and have installed a handful of solid floors, did an excellent job I’d say… but I’m but not a seasoned pro. I want to make up for that with good planning + patience :)

I lean to Option 2, because Option 1 requires *perfect* cuts to make that long hairline between the miters dead straight. The spokes will hide some discrepancy (and will mirror the ceiling beams). Option 1 also requires every piece in a ring to be the exact same width in order for the “ring lines” to look right – even a 5 1/64” piece will create gaps.

If I do Option 2… should install all the spokes up front or not? I say no – because I’m doing a glue-assist install (cleat-nails + stripes of Bona glue). I’ll have to dry-fit most pieces repeatedly to get a perfect fit… and once I’m there, I’ll have to remove the piece, add glue, put it back, and nail it. Problem is, pulling out a piece perfectly wedged in between 2 spokes is very likely to damage it.

So, here’s how I’d do it:

1. Install an octagonal medallion with 5” L sides (so that I can use 5” W flooring for the spokes).
2. Install just one spoke. Hold in place w/blocks.
3. Install flooring up to it, stopping where the next ray goes. Stay straight w/14’ L straight-edge.
4. Put a 14’ L straight-edge against the exposed edge, and sand any proud pieces to perfection (this is a major advantage of this method.
5. Install next spoke. (Final section requires wedging.)

Would really appreciate any thoughts  or general advice! I’m more nervous about this than the first time I framed a roof… I can’t find anyone in Texas who’s even done this before.

Comment: You're only asking for input on option 2, so why make us read about option 1? I was expecting this to be a "which is better" or "which should I do" question and was ready to close it. You may consider visiting [woodworking.se], as there are a lot of experienced woodworkers there, and this is as much woodworking as carpentry. For step 4, I'd suggest sanding after everything is down instead of one piece at a time. I can see piecemeal sanding ending up with every joint smooth, but overall waves across the floor.

Comment: Either way is as much art as it is skill.  I have no opinion as to which method, but care to applaud you for your patience.

Comment: The more I think about it, your only question is, "should install all the spokes up front or not?" which is opinion. My thought would be yes you should install the spokes first so you can fit each piece of flooring between them. If you leave them loose, you're trying to juggle hundreds of loose pieces. I'm not sure how steps 2 & 3 would work with loose spokes or where you're actually nailing pieces down. VtC - opinion based. An [edit] might change my mind.

Comment: The post says I lean to Option 2, and that's the case. I included Option 1 in case any carpenters more seasoned than me would advocate for it. Fitting flooring in between existing spokes seems unduly tough due to the abovementioned glue aspect. Juggling the loose pieces isn't really an issue, there's room. I'd like to nail every piece, hence the splines (aka slip tongues).

Comment: ("Lean to" meaning "lean to" not "have absolutely committed to")

Answer (score 1):

The upside to option 2 is that it would be really easy to use a tracksaw (or equivalent) to cut all your rough length rings in a perfect line to drop the spoke into place. You'd only get biscuits or splines on one side of the spoke, but my gut is that it would be fine.

Comment: Thanks Aloysius. To clarify though... the spokes would be made from flooring, so one side will have a tongue already. Are you suggesting just leaving the track-saw-cut flooring un-routed, then bringing the groove side of the spoke up to it?

Comment: I see. It would probably work to groove the rings and drop the spoke in. (The spoke might need a tiny bevel on the groove side.)

Comment: Or you could do it in 8 operations: ring, cut straight, groove ends on rings, insert spoke, assemble the next set of rings with spline that corresponds to the groove on the spoke, cut the rough ends of that set of rings and repeat. Only the last spoke wouldn’t be well fastened on one side.